# How to code a where clause into a calculated member?

Tags: ssas, mdx

The first query works as I needed.  But when I tried to rewrite in terms of a calculated member to put it in my cube, It crashed.

```
select non empty [Measures].[Demanda Real] on 0,
non empty [Agente Distribuidor].[Nombre Distribuidor].[Nombre Distribuidor].members on 1
from Demanda
where [SkSubmercadoUsuario]
```

[First MDX query results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Tys.png)

This is my failed try:

```
with member [Measures].[Demanda Real Dos] 
as
([Measures].[Demanda Real], [SkSubmercadoUsuario])
select [Measures].[Demanda Real Dos]  on 0,
non empty [Agente Distribuidor].[Nombre Distribuidor].[Nombre Distribuidor].members on 1
from Demanda
```

What I need is slice my cube by [SkSubmercadoUsuario], but it cannot be by a where clause. I need to create a measure that slices the measure by this Named Set [SkSubmercadoUsuario]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need to do something like this

```
with member [Measures].[Demanda Real Dos] 
as
SUM({[Sk Submercado Usuario].&[52], [Sk Submercado Usuario].&[622]}, 
     [Measures].[Demanda Real] )

select [Measures].[Demanda Real Dos]  on 0,
non empty [Agente Distribuidor].[Nombre Distribuidor].[Nombre Distribuidor].members on 1
from Demanda
```

Comment: I excuted your code suggestion and didn't work.  An error rised with the named set: [SkSubmercadoUsuario] - To clarify this named set contains the following set {[Sk Submercado Usuario].&[52], [Sk Submercado Usuario].&[622]}

Comment: Yes, you were right.  Your advice helped me so mucho.  At the end, I could not use the named set as you suggest but I put the atrributes that compound the set.  At the end this is the final MDX: --It works
with member [Measures].[Demanda Real Dos] 
as
SUM({Exists
([Permisos].[Sk Submercado].children,
StrToMember("[Permisos].[Diractivo].&[" + mid(username, instr(username, "\")+1) + "]"))}, 
     [Measures].[Demanda Real] )

select [Measures].[Demanda Real Dos]  on 0,
non empty [Agente Distribuidor].[Nombre Distribuidor].[Nombre Distribuidor].members on 1
from Demanda

Comment: Glad to help @AndrsFelipeDominguez

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you're trying to do. 
Do you just want to create a second measure [Measures].[Demanda Real] renamed as [Measures].[Demanda Real Dos] in your query or do you want to create your measure in the "calculation script part" of your cube ?
In the first case, I think you don't need to move the condition part. Try this :

```
with member [Measures].[Demanda Real Dos] 
as
([Measures].[Demanda Real])
select [Measures].[Demanda Real Dos]  on 0,
non empty [Agente Distribuidor].[Nombre Distribuidor].[Nombre Distribuidor].members on 1
from Demanda
where [SkSubmercadoUsuario]
```

Comment: Excume, my explanation wasn't understandable.  What I need is slice my cube by [SkSubmercadoUsuario], but I cannot be by a where clause.  I need to create a measure that slices the measure by this Named Set [SkSubmercadoUsuario]